# How to physically interpret the symmetric tensor product of 2 solutions of the right-handed Weyl equations?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, spinors

The Weyl equations are:

$$ \sigma^\mu \partial_{\mu} \psi = 0,$$

where $\psi$ is a section of $M \times \mathbb{C}^2$ over Minkowski spacetime $M$.

Let us say you have two solutions of the right-handed Weyl equations, say $\psi$ and $\nu$. Let us include the indices, so that the solutions can be denoted by $\psi^A$ and $\nu^A$, respectively, where $A = 1, 2$. Let us now form a new field, namely

$$ \psi^{(A} \nu^{B)} = \frac{1}{2}(\psi^A \nu^B + \psi^B \nu^A).$$

This new field, let us denote it by $\psi \odot \nu$, is thus a section of $M \times \operatorname{Sym}^2( \mathbb{C}^2 )$. Does this new field $\psi \odot \nu$ represent something from a physical perspective?

I think that $\psi \odot \nu$ is a solution of the natural extension of the Weyl equations to spinor fields having $2$ indices which are symmetric in both indices. So I guess one could get solutions of the extended Weyl equations this way. I am not sure if  they generate or not the space of all solutions of the extended Weyl equations or not. Do they? If not, how can one characterize the subspace of the solutions of the extended Weyl equations which are obtained this way?

Comment: FWIW, it transforms in the $(j_L,j_R)=(0,1)$ irrep of the Lorentz group.

Comment: It's a spin 1 spinorial tensor which can also be written with Lorentz indices. Since it is not left unchanged by a space inversion, i.e. it is not self-dual, we can't assign a physical interpretation to it.

Comment: @DanielC, doesn't a Lorentz vector transform in the $(j_L, j_R) = (1/2, 1/2)$ irrep of $\operatorname{Spin}(1,3)$? And this spinorial field lives in the $(j_L, j_R) = (0,1)$ irrep. So how can it also be written with Lorentz indices please? As to the parity comment, I think I understand it. For a spinor field to be physical, it must be invariant under the transformation induced by $P$, which is, in the case of $j_R = 0$, a quaternionic structure if $j_L$ is half-an-odd-integer, and a real structure if $j_L$ is non-negative integer. Do I understand your comment correctly please?